# How to create an extended ES6-class constructor from a provided base class and from additionally provided and to be mixed-in behavior?

Tags: javascript, mixins, composition, extends, es6-class

I tried to write a mixin function based on the ideas described [here](http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html) for inheritance. Method mixins are pretty easy, but I am struggling with constructor mixins.

I try to write a function, which takes a class and returns a new class, with an extended constructor.

This is my example:

```js
function extend_constructor(original, extension) {
  let extended = function (...args) {
    console.log("extended constructor")
    original.prototype.constructor.apply(this, args)
    extension.apply(this, args)
  }
  Object.defineProperty(extended, 'name', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(original, 'name'))
  extended.prototype = Object.create(original.prototype)
  Object.defineProperty(extended.prototype, 'constructor', {
    value: extended,
    writeable: true,
    configurable: true})
  return extended
}

function extension(id) {
  console.log(`Extension: ${id}`)
}
```

I works with function classes.

```js
function Basefunc(id) {
  console.log(`Basefunc: ${id}`)
}

new Basefunc(1)

const BasefuncEx = extend_constructor(Basefunc, extension)

new BasefuncEx(2)
```

But fails with ES6 classes:

```js
class Baseclass {
  constructor(id) {
    console.log(`Baseclass: ${id}`)
  }
}

new Baseclass(3)

const BaseclassEx = extend_constructor(Baseclass, extension)

new BaseclassEx(4)
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Class constructor Baseclass cannot be invoked without 'new'

But I think using `new` is not what I want, because `new` will create an instance of the original class and will apply the original constructor to it. I want to apply the original constructor of the original class to the instance of the extended class. And I am wondering how to do this with `new`.

Comment: Can you not use the `extends` keyword?

Comment: The error is exactly what's wrong. You're *not* calling the constructor with `new`. ES6 constructors *have* to be called with `new`. `.apply()` simply isn't this. You could use `new` or even `Reflect.construct()` but to be quite honest, I'm not sure what the point of the exercise is. The article is from five years before ES6 was released. It was written before even `Object.create()` had wide support. It describes a way to handle objects that is not really quite in line as the `class` syntax of ES6 which aims to simplify that. And allows for other approaches, as well.

Comment: @VLAZ `Reflect.construct()` is just an alternative to `new`, which does more or less the same. This does not help me, because I want to create something, which can be passed to `new`. Therefor I can not call `new` myself, because if I would do, `new` would be called twice. I want to compose a constructor and not an object.

Comment: But you *are calling the constructor* with `original.prototype.constructor.apply(this, args)`. That's also why you get the error, since it's called without `new`. If you wanted to compose it and execute it *later* then...you shouldn't be calling it. Yet if you don't call it at that point, how would you even produce an instance when the entire point of the code in the `extended` function is to produce an instance and decorate it with extensions?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function createSubClassWithMixinBehavior(
  subClassName, SuperClass, withBehavior
) {
  return ({
    [subClassName]: class extends SuperClass {
      constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        withBehavior.apply(this, args);
      }
    },
  })[subClassName];
}

class BaseType {
  constructor(id) {
    console.log(`constructing the BaseType logs ... ${ id }`);
  }
}
function extension(id) {
  this.id = id;
  console.log(`applying / mixin-in the extension logs ... ${ id }`);
}
const baseType = new BaseType(3);
const subType = new (
  createSubClassWithMixinBehavior('SubType', BaseType, extension)
)(4);

console.log({
  baseType,
  subType,
  nameOfSuperClass: baseType.constructor.name,
  nameOfSubClass: subType.constructor.name,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: My aim was to mixin, not to inherit. But I dont care anymore.

Comment: @ceving ... Your aim actually was/is ... _"I try to write a function, which takes a class and returns a new class, with an extended constructor."_ ... The above solution comes up with a literal implementation of the quoted/cited sentence/specification of yours where the constructor not only is part of the extended class, but also applies the provided (function based) mixin.