# Overwrite call in javascript object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, super, extends

I am a newbie in JavaScript, trying to extend class variable prototype without inheritance

```js
class Z{
    constructor(){}
    a(){console.log('a')}
    get b(){console.log('b')}
    c(){console.log('c')}
}

class B{
    constructor(z){
        this.z = z;
    }
}

let z = new Z();
let b = new B(z);
b.a(); // error
b.b; // error
```

the `B` class is intended to be just a method mixin and variable bundle, however for some reason, I cannot extend `Z` to `B`. When I calling a method, or retrieve a `prop` on `z`, can I **inspect whether it can be accessed through `this.z`, if so, return it directly**?

Any ideas of how to write this structure will be more than appreciated.

---

The reason I cannot use `extend` keyword directly, is that `Z` is provided by a lib, and the instance is constructed in a callable, or static on class. I am not familiar with `function class constructor` at all, things such as `_super` or `__proto__`.

And why I thought about this is that, you can define a dunder `__call__` or `__getitem__` in python to serve this purpose. I am not sure if it is possible at all, I will be so glad if you can give me a hand. Something functional like:

```js
class Z{
  a()
    try{
      return this.z.a()
    }catch(){/}
  }
}
```

But would apply for any retrieving attempt.

---

Thanks all comments for suggestion.
Note following are not minimum working example but real life occasion.

```js
/* lib source code */
function fromTextArea(textarea, options) {
  options = options ? copyObj(options) : {};
  options.value = textarea.value;
  if (!options.tabindex && textarea.tabIndex) { options.tabindex = textarea.tabIndex; }
  if (!options.placeholder && textarea.placeholder) { options.placeholder = textarea.placeholder; }
  // Set autofocus to true if this textarea is focused, or if it has
  // autofocus and no other element is focused.
  if (options.autofocus == null) {
    var hasFocus = activeElt();
    options.autofocus = hasFocus == textarea ||
      textarea.getAttribute("autofocus") != null && hasFocus == document.body;
  }

  function save() { textarea.value = cm.getValue(); }

  var realSubmit;
  if (textarea.form) {
    on(textarea.form, "submit", save);
    // Deplorable hack to make the submit method do the right thing.
    if (!options.leaveSubmitMethodAlone) {
      var form = textarea.form;
      realSubmit = form.submit;
      try {
        var wrappedSubmit = form.submit = function () {
          save();
          form.submit = realSubmit;
          form.submit();
          form.submit = wrappedSubmit;
        };
      } catch (e) { }
    }
  }

  options.finishInit = function (cm) {
    cm.save = save;
    cm.getTextArea = function () { return textarea; };
    cm.toTextArea = function () {
      cm.toTextArea = isNaN; // Prevent this from being ran twice
      save();
      textarea.parentNode.removeChild(cm.getWrapperElement());
      textarea.style.display = "";
      if (textarea.form) {
        off(textarea.form, "submit", save);
        if (!options.leaveSubmitMethodAlone && typeof textarea.form.submit == "function") { textarea.form.submit = realSubmit; }
      }
    };
  };

  textarea.style.display = "none";
  var cm = CodeMirror(function (node) { return textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(node, textarea.nextSibling); },
    options);
  return cm
}

// a part of the application I am working on
class CodeEditor{
    constructor(
        container, 
        generic, 
        types, 
        modes, 
        options, 
    ){
        this.generic = generic;
        this.types = types;
        this.modes = modes;

        /*
        .code-container
            .cm-header-bar
                .cm-code-compile-wrapper
                button.dropdown-button
            textarea
        */
        this.container = container;
        this.textarea = container.querySelector('textarea');
        this.header = this.container.querySelector('.cm-header-bar');
        this.compileBtnWrapper = this.header.querySelector('.cm-code-compile-wrapper');
        this.compileBtn = document.createElement('div');
        this.compileBtn.classList.add('cm-code-compile');
        this.compileBtn.innerText = 'compile';
        this.options = options;

        this.mode = this.textarea.getAttribute('id');
        this.options.mode.name = this.mode;
        this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.textarea, this.options);
        // editor setup
        this.editor.on("gutterClick", function(cm, n) {
            let info = cm.lineInfo(n);
            cm.setGutterMarker(n, "breakpoints", info.gutterMarkers ? null : makeMarker());
        });
        // compilable
        if(this.mode !== this.generic)this.compilable();
        this.dropdown = dropdown(this.header.querySelector('.dropdown-button'), '预先处理', generic);
        Object.keys(this.modes).forEach(mode=>{
            this.dropdown.addOption(mode, ()=>{
                htmlEditor.setOption('mode', { name: this.name, globalVars: true });
                this.mode = mode;
                this.editor.refresh();
                play();
                if(mode !== this.generic)this.compilable();
            }, mode === this.mode);
        });
    }

    get name(){
        return this.types[this.mode];
    }

    compilable(){
        this.compileBtnWrapper.appendChild(this.compileBtn);
        let temp = {};
        const oxidize = () => {
            this.compileBtn.onclick = () => {
                temp.code = this.getValue();
                temp.mode = this.mode ;
                // compile
                this.dropdown.onOption(this.generic);
                this.setValue(this.modes[this.mode]());
                this.options.mode.name = this.types[this.generic];
                this.setOption('mode', this.options.mode);
                this.compileBtn.classList.add('active');
                this.compileBtn.innerText = 'restore';
                // undo
                reduce();
            }
        }
        const reduce = () => {
            this.compileBtn.onclick = () => {
                this.dropdown.onOption(temp.mode);
                this.setValue(temp.code);
                this.options.mode.name = temp.mode;
                this.setOption('mode', this.types[temp.mode]);
                this.compileBtn.classList.remove('active');
                this.compileBtn.innerText = 'compile';
                // undo
                oxidize();
            }
        }
        oxidize();
    }

    /* 
    I am optimizing a big proj, the instance used to be a 
    CodeMirror. However, it produces a lot of redundant 
    self-occurring parts, and I do not want to pass parameters
    all day, therefore I wrapped it with a CodeEditor instance
    However, other code in this project would call the CodeMirror 
    prototype method, since I cannot find a way to extends 
    CodeMirror methods from this.editor to this, I need to 
    redefine them all (following are only a tiny part)
    */
    setValue(v){return this.editor.setValue(v)}
    getValue(){return this.editor.getValue()}
    setOption(...args){return this.editor.setOption(...args)};
    focus(){return this.editor.focus()}

    // more functionality
    compiled(){return this.modes[this.mode]() || ''};
    raw(){return this.getValue().trimEnd()}
}
```

CodeMirror 5.63.3: https://codemirror.net/5/doc/releases.html

Sorry that I did not find a CDN that provides non-minimised code.

Comment: "I am a newbie in JavaScript." pro tip: whenever there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do what you're trying to do instead of contorting the language to fit your design, it's probably time to rethink your design. Here's another: although I realize this is an example, a getter should really not have side-effects. "is that Z instance is constructed in a callable, or static on class" that is probably your problem, you should post that code (or a stripped-down version of it).

Comment: "*the `B` class is intended to be just a method mixin and variable bundle*" - it's not really clear what that means. What do you want to do with `Z`, which appears to come from a third-party library, and whose instances you are not constructing yourself?

Comment: @Bergi, sorry that my words confused you,  I have made some modification and a detailed example

Comment: @Weilory ... The OP might check out another, late provided, approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, javascript doesn't provide `getattr` like in python, so your best bet is to create proxy methods manually, for example:

```
class B {
    constructor(z) {
        let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(z)
        for (let p of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
            let val = proto[p]
            if (typeof val === 'function')
                this[p] = val.bind(z)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `val.bind(z)` would invoke `Z` methods in the context of the passed `z` object (="facade"). You can also do `val.bind(this)`, which would use the `B` object as a context (="mixin").

Comment: This only overwrite function keeping original MRO and, worked a treat!

Comment: For viewers if you want the prop proto on inheritance only, which can be overwritten in this class, modify the line to `if(!this[p]) this[p] = val.bind(z) `

Comment: Note that if `Z` itself is a subclass, then the inherited methods will not be available to `b`. To me this code feels like fighting against prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @trincot: the OP seems to want delegation (see `this.z.a` in the question), not inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the `Z` prototype in the prototype chain like this:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, Z.prototype);
```

This establishes this chain:

```
b → B.prototype → Z.prototype → Object.prototype
```

```js
// Library code
class Z{
    constructor() {}
    a()     { console.log('a') }
    get b() { console.log('b') }
    c()     { console.log('c') }
}
const z = new Z();
// End library code

class B{
    constructor() {}
    x()     { console.log('x') }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, Z.prototype);

let b = new B();
b.a();
b.b;
b.x(); 

z.test = 1;
console.log(b.test); // Undefined (see next snippet)
```

If you need `b` to **also** have access to whatever instance properties have been set on `z` (so not on its proto object), then add one more step in the chain like this:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, z);
```

This establishes this chain:

```
b → B.prototype → z → Z.prototype → Object.prototype
```

```js
// Library code
class Z{
    constructor() {}
    a()     { console.log('a') }
    get b() { console.log('b') }
    c()     { console.log('c') }
}
const z = new Z();
// End library code

class B{
    constructor() {}
    x()     { console.log('x') }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, z);

let b = new B();
b.a();
b.b;
b.x(); 

z.test = 1;
console.log(b.test); // 1
```

In case `b` must be created as an instance of `Z.prototype`, and not of `B.prototype`, then you should actually not define the `B` class at all, but define a decorator function:

```
function decorateNewZ() {
    return Object.assign(new Z(), {
        // Any extra methods
        x() { console.log('x') }
    });
}
```

```js
// Library code
class Z{
    constructor() {}
    a()     { console.log('a') }
    get b() { console.log('b') }
    c()     { console.log('c') }
}
const z = new Z();
// End library code

function decorateZ() {
    return Object.assign(new Z(), {
        // Any extra methods
        x() { console.log('x') }
    });
}


let b = decorateZ();
b.a();
b.b;
b.x();
```

Comment: This is purely magic, thanks very much. I tried to add this to the end of constructor, however overrides all `MRO` defined methods, guess I have to do it in iteration and conditional to decide which part to overwrite. ^v^

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *"at the end of constructor"*, but it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: `class Z{constructor(){}a(){console.log('a')}get b(){console.log('b')}}class B{constructor(z){this.z = z;Object.setPrototypeOf(this, this.z)}n(){console.log('n')}} let z = new Z(); let b = new B(z); b.a(); b.n(); /* error */`

Comment: No, that is not good. Don't change an object's prototype in the constructor. Then you remove `B.prototype` from the chain. That's not the idea I presented in my answer. The line of code I presented is just to be executed *once* after the definition of `B`, and no repetition of it is needed. New instances created by calling the `B` constructor will still see the modified chain.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation now I see, this one-liner would elegantly extends all `props` and `methods`, and is very clear for inheritance structure, which is a perfect solution for **extending without `extends`**. The answer is great, I reckon it just an occasion that @gog ‘s code fit my app more, since it only add method definition, which the explicit scope is maintained within `this.editor`, any assignment to the instance will not potentially conflict with lib class feature.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking that your request to do it without `extends` was more a syntax requirement, but now I see you want to make `b` an immediate instance of `Z.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

An entirely ES6-class based approach provides everything (all of the necessary prototype (re)wiring) for free.

The following implementation returns a class which extends the constructor of any provided type-instance (either of class' or of pure constructor functions or of built-ins). It also supports the naming of the returned class constructor.

```js
function createExtendedClassFromInstanceType(
  className, instance
) {
  const { constructor: SuperClass } = instance;
  if ('function' === typeof SuperClass) {
    return ({
      [className]: class extends SuperClass {
        constructor(...args) {
          super(...args);
          // own implementation
        }
      }
    })[className];
  }
}

class NonAccessibleType {
  constructor() {
  }
  // all prototypal
  a() {
    console.log('`a()` logs from custom prototype');
  }
  get b() {
    console.log('`b` getter logs from custom prototype');
  }
  c () {
    console.log('`c()` logs from custom prototype');
  }
}
const customInstance = new NonAccessibleType;

const SubType = createExtendedClassFromInstanceType(
  'SubType', customInstance
);
let subType = new SubType;

console.log('invoking `subType.a()` ...');
subType.a();
console.log('accessing `subType.b` ...');
subType.b;

console.log(
  '\ncustomInstance.constructor.name ...',
  customInstance.constructor.name
);
console.log(
  'subType.constructor.name ...',
  subType.constructor.name
);

console.log(
  '\n(customInstance instanceof NonAccessibleType) ?..',
  (customInstance instanceof NonAccessibleType)
);
console.log(
  '(customInstance instanceof SubType) ?..',
  (customInstance instanceof SubType)
);
console.log(
  '(subType instanceof NonAccessibleType) ?..',
  (subType instanceof NonAccessibleType)
);
console.log(
  '(subType instanceof SubType) ?..',
  (subType instanceof SubType)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Note**, regarding the OP's mentioning of ...*

> *"... the B class is intended to be just a method mixin and variable bundle ..."*

... the OP might have a look into the answer of [*"How to create an extended ES6-class constructor from a provided base class and from additionally provided and to be mixed-in behavior?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389741/how-to-create-an-extended-es6-class-constructor-from-a-provided-base-class-and-f/75632204#75632204) where the same base technique of a class creating factory got used for covering also the mixin aspect instead of just the one of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Proxy although Proxies ain't the most performant thing in JS.

```js
class Bar {
  value = 0;

  foo() {
    return "Bar.foo()";
  }

  bar(val) {
    this.value = val;
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    //this.editor = new Bar();
    this.$editor = new Bar();
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype, new Proxy(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype),
  {
    get(t, p, r) {
      //return Reflect.get(p !== "editor" && r.editor || t, p);
      return Reflect.get(r.$editor, p);
    },
  })
)

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.foo());
console.log(f.value);
f.bar(42);
console.log(f.value);
```